# How can an assignment call a function?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

My activity:

```
class PlayerDetails : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityPlayerDetailsBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_player_details)
    }
```

How can an assignment (`binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_player_details`) call a function? (`setContentView()`)?

Comment: the assignment calls nothing. binding is just assigned the value that is returned from that methodcall.

Comment: Then how is `setContentView()` being called? My views in my activity are showing up.

Comment: it is called because you wrote code that calls it? it's right here: DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_player_details)

Comment: Take a look at DataBindingUtil source code here, https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/data-binding/+/e4cd38824a6627b9fef229c549c636e35ad63b5f/library/src/main/java/android/databinding/DataBindingUtil.java

Comment: But it's not `DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_player_details)` (function call) it's `binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_player_details)` (assignment)

Comment: @Zorgan the assignment is a separate thing that is happening. What you need to know is how a statement is executed. In your example, the function setContentView is called and the value returned from that method is assigned to the binding variable.

Comment: @Zorgan No, it's both. You need to take the order of execution in mind. Your assignment is the last thing that happens in that line of code.
The execution order is, first execute the function call to setContentView() and this method returns a ViewDataBinding.
Then the second step is using the returned ViewDataBinding to assign to your binding variable.

Comment: @Zorgan `binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_player_details)` is an assignment statement, the right hand side (RHS) is a value or an expression that returns a value, the left hand side (LHS) is always a variable. First, the RHS will be calculated then assign the value to variable in LHS. In your case, `DataBindingUtil.setContentView` method will be calculated (it called `setContentView` of the activity internally) and return a value then assign the value to `binding` variable.

Comment: Thanks - a few questions. 1. What is the point of this function: https://i.imgur.com/x1SinhY.png before `setContentView()` is called (https://i.imgur.com/moCWwD0.png)?  2. What does it mean to call a function "internally"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look at this example:

```
fun main() {
   val newString = createString()
   println("String was created " + newString)
}

fun createString(): String {
    println("Hello, world!!!")
    return "new string"
}
```

Go ahead and run it [here](https://pl.kotl.in/BJVvDknBN)
If you'll run it you will see in the output:

> Hello, world!!!
>
> String was created new string

But where the `Hello, world!!!` comes from? How the assignment could print another text into log?

The thing is that the `val newString = createString()` is not just an assignment. A pure assignment will be `var s = "s"` for example, where just a new value is assigned to the variable. But here we see a method call `createString()` which returns the result (`String`) which is assigned to a `val newString`. You can interpreter it like this:

```
val temptString = createString()
val newString = tempString
```

So when the `createString()` method calls, internally it prints out the `Hello, world!!!`.

Now, please take a look at your own code. Same things happens there.
First it calls a function `DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_player_details)`, which calls `setContentView()` (you're looking for) under the hood and returns a `ViewDataBinding` object. Which will be assigned to the `binding` property later.

Comment: Thanks. What exactly is `DataBindingComponent` and where does it fit in all this? Source code: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/data-binding/+/e4cd38824a6627b9fef229c549c636e35ad63b5f/library/src/main/java/android/databinding/DataBindingUtil.java

Comment: It's something from internals of the `DataBindingUtil`. I honestly don't know